# link_to with remote: true still refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a link_to to add(create instance) or delete(destroy instance) a deal to a wishlist, it looks like a heart and when clicked it create or delete a wishlist instance. It is working so far, but only problem is that it keeps refreshing the page, i've added remote: true but i keeps refreshing every time i add or remove from wishlist. I am using Rails 6

```
<%= link_to current_user.wishlist?(@deal) ? current_user.wishlist?(@deal) : deal_wishlists_path(@deal), class: "btn btn-light", method: current_user.wishlist?(@deal) ? :delete : :post, remote: true do %>
      <% if current_user.wishlist?(@deal) %>
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
        <span>Enregistré</span>
      <% else %>
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        <span>Wishlister</span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>


class WishlistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_deal, except: :destroy
  def create
    @wishlist = @deal.wishlists.create!(user_id: current_user.id)
    redirect_to deal_path(@deal)
  end

  def destroy
    @wishlist = Wishlist.find(params[:id])
    @wishlist.destroy
    redirect_to deal_path(@wishlist.deal)
  end

  private

  def find_deal
    @deal = Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
  end
end
```

thanks

Comment: It's not the button, it's your controller. It does a redirect every time. To update the page without reloading it, you need to handle ajaxy requests differently. Take a look at this post, for example: https://medium.com/swlh/ajax-calls-in-rails-delete-actions-without-reloading-the-page-934fc1b4b9cd Should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use  `redirect_to deal_path(...)` in your controller. Just remove them.